# Installation of missing C libraries when installing HDBC-Sqlite3

Tags: haskell, sqlite

I am trying to set up my PC running windows XP to run the **Haskell Platform** and the **SQLite3** database. I also have to install 2 additional Libraries from Hackage database (home of the additional haskell libraries)

1. **HDBC**
2. **HDBC.sqlite3**

I downloaded the Haskell platform and installed it on the following location on my computer

**C:\Program Files\Haskell Platform\2013.2.0.0**

from the command line I installed the HDBC library with the following command

**C:\Document and setting\oke\cabal install HDBC**

from the command line I tried to install the HDBC-sqlite3

**C:\Document and setting\oke\cabal install HDBC-sqlite3**

this gave an error message stating …...

**cabal missing dependency on foreign library
*Missing C library:sqlite3
ExitFailure 1**

please can somebody give details as to how I get the missing C libraries and 
what exact folders, do I place them in ?
and how I install the HDBC-sqlite3 library using cabal ?

Do I install the **Sqlite3** before installing libraries and what folder is best to do so?

Answer (score 1):

Get the SQLite DLL from the [SQLite download page](http://sqlite.org/download.html), copy it to somewhere sensible (say, `C:\sqlite3`, and *not* Program Files nor anywhere in the Windows directory), add your chosen directory to the PATH (see the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/694351/setting-library-path-for-win32-console-applications) for details) and, finally, install `HDBC-sqlite3` with cabal. In general, cabal will not install C libraries, so whenever you install a package which depends on one you will have to set it up in your system beforehand.