# How to use Python Anaconda numpy with Blender?

Tags: numpy, anaconda, blender

I try to use Python Anaconda inside Blender 2.80
I've renamed the Python folder inside Blender as _Python
I've add Anaconda/Python to my PATH environment variables

So, Blender use the Anaconda Python distribution

But, problem with numpy :

When I try 
import numpy

I got error messages, with DLL not found

What's wrong ?

Thank you

Alain

Answer (score 0):

When programs are compiled they get linked to shared libraries, some of these libraries are part of the compiler installation and some are system installed.

The issue you are getting is that when blender starts, it first finds an older version of the gcc libraries which is adequate for blenders needs, but then when an addon using numpy is loaded, numpy needs a newer version of the same library, this fails as you can't open two versions of the same library.

The solution is to configure the search order used to find libraries.

- For *nix systems set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to include the newest version of gcc installed. This can be done in a script used to start blender or in your environment settings, such as `.bashrc`, `.profile` or `.cshrc` by adding something like (adjust to match a gcc installation that you have)

  ```
  export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib/gcc8/
  ```
- For Windows, (untested) looking at the [search order](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22528657/2684771) would indicate making a link of `libgcc_s.so` into the blender installation directory could be a solution. Another possibility might be using a script that changes to the folder containing the gcc libs and then starting blender.